# How would I open a program inside of a windows form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want a program, let's say google chrome, to open inside of a windows form but not be able to be moved outside of the form or seen on the taskbar.

Comment: Are you talking about an arbitrary program, or specifically Chrome? What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

You can't embed arbitrary applications into yours, unless they provide an API for that. If you want to embed a browser, take a look at WebBrowser control or Awesomium project that happens to be a .Net wrapper for Chromium.

Answer (score 0):

Although rather hacky, this can be done by using the SetParent ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms633541(v=vs.85).aspxwindows ) API function.

I have done this when I've needed to integrate with a buggy video libraries which would crash periodically. It was not acceptable to have the main user interface crash when the video library died so I spawned another application to show the video, and parented it to a window in the main application.

Once parented you may want to use other functions to move it around or resize it e.g. MoveWindow.

Using this method can have some side effects which you may need to manage.